# TCP packet drop (ns3)

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, ns-3

I am new to ns3 network simulator and wanted to know how to get the number of packet drops in a TCP connection. I know of the following command:

```
devices.Get (1)->TraceConnectWithoutContext ("PhyRxDrop", MakeBoundCallback (&RxDrop, stream));
```

But this is helpful only for a single TCP connection over a p2p link. In my topology, there is a single p2p connection but 2 applications using TCP over that same p2p link and I would like to know individually for each TCP connection the number of dropped packets. I have researched online quite a lot but was unable to find any resources. Kindly point to some resources or give the class name which I can use to detect TCP connection-specific packet losses.

The above command as of now combines the packet losses for both the connections and outputs them to the `stream` because they are over the same p2p link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of `RxDrop` tells me you're using referring to fourth.cc in [the ns-3 tutorial](https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.32/tutorial/singlehtml/index.html#walkthrough-fourth-cc). Connecting to the PhyRxDrop TraceSource will result in the requested CallBack being invoked for each dropped packet. *ns-3* doesn't have a packet filter such that the CallBack would only be invoked for some packets.

However, you can determine which connection a packet corresponds to. Simply strip the packet headers, and inspect the port numbers. Remember every connection is defined by a unique 4-tuple: (host IP, host port, destination IP, destination port).

```cpp
static void
RxDrop(Ptr<const Packet> packet) {
    /* 
     * Need to copy packet since headers need to be removed
     * to be inspected. Alternatively, remove the headers,
     * and add them back.
     */
    Ptr<Packet> copy = packet->Copy();

    // Headers must be removed in the order they're present.
    PppHeader pppHeader;
    copy->RemoveHeader(pppHeader);
    Ipv4Header ipHeader;
    copy->RemoveHeader(ipHeader);
    TcpHeader tcpHeader;
    copy->RemoveHeader(tcpHeader);

    std::cout << "Source IP: ";
    ipHeader.GetSource().Print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Source Port: " << tcpHeader.GetSourcePort() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Destination IP: ";
    ipHeader.GetDestination().Print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Destination Port: " << tcpHeader.GetDestinationPort() << std::endl;
}
```